# undefined variable model in yii

Tags: php, templates, yii

I am getting the error `undefined variable model`. I have the following codes in my view and controller. My aim is to search the results and show it in same page. I have tried the following things but its not working.

Again,I this this the conventional yii method to do so,or do I have to use a search() function from model SearchEmployee().?

```
public function actionSearch()
{
      $model = new SearchEmployee();

       /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
  if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

      $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category_id'];
      $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
      $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

      $model = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
      'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND key_skills like '%$skills%' AND experience=$experience",
      ));

      $this->render('search',$model);
  }

  /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
  $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
}
```

In View Section: search.php//To display and search the desired result

```
<div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_id',$list,array('empty' =>'(Select a Category')); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
</div>

  <div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Experience'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'experience'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'experience'); ?>    
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
</div>



<div class="view">

  <h1>Results </h1>

  <div class="view" id="id">

     <h1> Records Display </h1>

     <h4>Name:        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?></h4>
     <h4>Skills:      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'experience'); ?></h4>
     <h4>Experience:  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'skills'); ?></h4>
     <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp ;<?php echo $form->labelEx('VIew Details'); ?></h5>
   </div>

 </div>
```

In view section I am using the search and view results option in the same form.I am getting the error after clicking the search button.Is this the correct way to do

Comment: The error usually shows a line number and a trace as well. Do you have that?

Comment: Nathan...its here in view page search.php '<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>'

Comment: By the way your "find" query looks very unsafe, if not invalid. You should study the correct way to use ActiveRecords

Comment: Your search.php shows a submit button but not "form" - are you sure everything is here?

Comment: yes...I am not following the conventions correcly,just have started to use yii.

Comment: ok, i found your bug (see answer), but you will probably have more issues after.

Comment: search.php have two  fields in <div>class ="row"<div>.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50879/discussion-between-nathan-h-and-saji)

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
                  'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND
         key_skills like '%$skills%' AND experience=$experience",
));
```

There is error here. You can't use find in that way.

```
public function find($condition='',$params=array())

$model = SearchEmployee::model()->find("category_id=$category AND
         key_skills like '%$skills%' AND experience=$experience");
```

But better

```
$model = SearchEmployee::model()->find("category_id=:category AND key_skills like :skill AND experience=:experience", array(
    'category'=>$category,
    'skill'=>'%'.$skills.'%',
    'experience'=>$experience
));
```

Comment: I would recommend `new CDbCriteria` - especially when you explain it to a new Yii user.

Comment: author it seems like i helped you, why didn't you marked my answer as decision?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
$this->render('search',$model);
```

First it's invalid because it should be:

```
$this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
```

But also it's unnecessary because you already have it lower in your code.

Comment: Nathan...now I am getting error  "Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414".After above mentioned change

Comment: Like I said - you will get more errors after you fix this one.